# Go: template.ParseFiles() doesn't work with {{.active}} but does for {{printf "%s" .active}}

Tags: html, go

Lets say the body of my html file like so

```
<body>
    <h2>Current number of players: {{.active}}</h2>
</body>
```

And my go code looks like

```
type page struct{
    active string
}
t, _ template.ParseFiles("page.html")
t.Execute(w,page{active: "No Players are Online"})
```

When I run the code, I get a blank screen. When I change {{.active}} to {{printf "%s" .active}} it works.

Do I always need to include printf? I guess I'm confused by the documentation.

Thanks!

Comment: Using `printf` still does not make it work: https://play.golang.org/p/dlSsp2y3Bj. Don't ignore errors!

Comment: Further to Tim's comment to **never ignore errors**, I'll point out that if you look at the error in *either* case it would tell you the exact issue: "active is an unexported field of struct type main.page".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make `active` property capitalized. Like so:

```
type page struct{
    Active string
}
t, _ template.ParseFiles("page.html")
t.Execute(w,page{Active: "No Players are Online"})
```

and template

```
<body>
    <h2>Current number of players: {{.Active}}</h2>
</body>
```

Go exports only capitalized struct properties to other modules.

Comment: Wow! Somehow, I missed that in the documentation. That solved my issue! Thank you so much!